# simple algorithm: count 2 numbers for j2me mobile devices

Tags: java-me

I need now to do a command action for two buttons: "exit" as in notifyDestroyed() and an "Ok" button. How can I implement in commandAction those 2 different buttons?

Comment: I think you will need to be much more specific about what you're trying to do, and what you want, before anyone will be able to help you.

Comment: Your question is not clear. if u want to add two numbers means u can do simple arithmetic program. or trying to post briefly.

Answer (score 0):

have u tried for the Keychar method?
u can detect the keys that are pressed by the user and apply whatever u want to do on that

Comment: no I haven't try Keychar. Sorry I'm new in this field. I am trying to enter from my cell keyboard 2 numbers and then count them and return on the screen the answer. Actually I'm trying to do a binary search but this is a star for me! If you have any suggestions I'll be thankful!

Answer (score 0):

Hey you can try keychar as follows:

```
protected boolean keyChar(char character, int status, int time)
    {
        if (character == Keypad.KEY_ENTER)
        {
            // do what u want
        }
        return super.keyChar(character, status, time);
    }
```

you can test for any key u want.
Its a sample

Comment: thanks a lot ! Any chance you'd know a book about j2me for beginners?